# Disable Save button if specific fields, including a datepicker, are empty with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to disable the Save button  as long as three specific fields are empty. One field is a simple input text box, the other is a dropdown list, and the last is a datepicker.

This is what I've done so far:

HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="0">A</option>
<option value="1">B</option>
<option value="2">C</option>
</select>
<input id="summary"></input>
<input id="myDate"></input>
<input type="button" id="save" value="Save Me" disabled="disabled"></input>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myDate').datepicker();
//$('#save').prop("disabled", true);

$('#mySelect, #summary,#myDate').on('change', function () {

if ($('#mySelect').find('option:selected').val() === "0" && $('#summary').val().length < 10 && 
//$('#myDate').datepicker("getDate") === null) { //---I tried this also
$('#myDate').val() === '') {
    //  $('#save').prop("disabled", false); //---I tried this also
    $('#save').removeAttr("disabled");

} else {
    $('#save').prop("disabled", true);
}

});
```

I also tried with `keyup`, and no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Update: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emfuentes27/n2u9fv1g/)

Comment: What does "no luck" means? Have you got any errors in console? Where is your jQuery code? In a DOM ready event?

Comment: @Marcos, it means, that it doesn't work. No error on console. I created this [http://jsfiddle.net/emfuentes27/n2u9fv1g/] (Fiddle), may help. Thanks!

Comment: "it means, that it doesn't work" I assume it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have your comparisons backwards.  You're currently removing the disabled attribute under these conditions:

```
if ($('#mySelect').find('option:selected').val() === "0" && $('#summary').val().length < 10 && $('#myDate').val() === '')
```

try changing it to this:

```
if ($('#mySelect').find('option:selected').val() != "0" && $('#summary').val().length != 0 && $('#myDate').val() != '')
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzjcvtyx/)

Comment: Perfect, that would do it, the only change I made to your suggestion was that I need to be greater than 10 characters `$('#summary').val().length > 10`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myDate").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
      alert('ok');
    if ($('#mySelect').val()!= "" && $('#summary').val()!= "" && $('#myDate').val() != ""){

        $('#save').removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {

        $('#save').prop("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  }
});
```

on datepicker change event will not work use this to validate